# How can I export png layers to flash? (GIMP)

Tags: export, swf

I am a GIMP user and I would like to create a flash animated image from PNG in order to preserve the colour quality that otherwise gif fails to deliver. I've searched the web but I am having problems since I cannot find a step by step "tutorial" how to install the script/plug in.

Answer (score 1):

Gimp does not natively support export to SWF animations.

However ther is a Python [plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27991) which claims to be able to create a SWF Flash animation of PNG layers. This plugin makes use of the tool **png2swf** available through the [SWFTOOLS collection](http://www.swftools.org/) of flash utilities.

Linux users may get **png2swf** through their software repositories. For Windows users there are binaries from the [project's download page](http://www.swftools.org/download.html).

It may be more convenient howveer to just run the **png2swf** tool from a folder containing a numbered set of png frames to stitch them together to a SWF animation. This requires exporting each layer as a numbered PNG from Gimp to the designated animation folder.

From there we can run the tool in a command line with the following syntax:

```
png2swf -o file.swf -r <rate> *.png
```

Where the (optional) option `-r` specifies the resulting framerate per second.

More options can be found on the [manpage for png2swf](http://www.swftools.org/png2swf.html).

Comment: "From there we can run the tool in a command line with the following syntax:

png2swf -o file.swf -r <rate> *.png"

I didn't understand this part. Are you talking about windows "cmd"?

Comment: You did not say what OS you're on. In Windows this is the "Command Prompt".

Comment: Alternatively you can open "Run command" (Windows + R key). Note that you will then have to type in the full paths to the command (if it was not added to your PATH environment), the outfile, and the png files.